# Routing in Reactjs App running with Tornado webserver doesn't work

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, reactjs

I am going to run a Reactjs app by Tornado (Python) webserver.

The routing system in Reactjs does not work.

For example:

```
https://localhost/        (Works!)
https://localhost/login   (Error 404!)
```

It seems the error comes from Tornado.
The following is the main files:

app.py:

```
  return tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/subscription", SubscriptionHandler),
    (r"/user/authenticate", AuthenticateHandler),
    (r"/user/register", RegistrationHandler),
    (r"/static/js/(.*)", tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, {"path": js_root}),
    (r"/static/css/(.*)", tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, {"path": css_root}),
    (r"/static/lib/(.*)", tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, {"path": node_modules}),
    (r"/(.*)", tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, {"path": widget_root, "default_filename": "index.html"})
], cookie_secret="1234567890")
```

App.js:

```
render() {
    return(
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" component={Profile} exact/>
          <Route path="/login" component={Login} exact/>
          <Route path="/signup" component={Signup} exact/>
          <Route path="/subscription" component={Subscription} exact/>
          <Route path="/payment" component={PaymentMethod} exact/>
          <Route component={Error}/>
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I found out the what issue is. Instead of using `<BrowserRouter>` tag I used `<HashRouter>` and it is solved